# Method or Methods To View & Copy Notes Besides On Your Device

Tags: file-transfer, notes

Recently i had been working on my mobile instead of my laptop and that turned into a problem. I had been writing notes and saving documents on a word processor. When i finally got home i found out that though i could transfer the documents to my laptop i had saved i couldn't transfer the notes files. My friend suggested that i copy the notes on a word file and then transfer that. Is their a quicker way or ways to copying my notes. Thank You In Advance for Any Help You Provide

Comment: Google Docs? Google Keep? Google Drive? Dropbox?

Comment: What notes app do you use? If its Google Keep, it's synced online. Try accessing https://keep.google.com from your laptop, you can find your notes there is they have been synced (i.e., the phone had an internet connection and Google Keep was the notes app you used).

Answer (score 0):

I use [Evernote](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.evernote&hl=en), which can be used offline and can be synched at a later time. It also has a [web app](https://evernote.com/) for online access, and a [desktop app](https://evernote.com/download/) as well.